# Jspdf Flask TypeError element.className.split

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jspdf

I have a view which dynamically generates google charts using JQuery load() and I  need to convert that **div** to a PDF. I tried the commonly found examples of **jsPDF from HTML** which returns this error

> Uncaught TypeError: element.className.split is not a function at elementHandledElsewhere

I tried python pdfkit and sent the data using ajax It does the job but I can't figure out how to send the response back. And Yes I have google searched this error and even that code returns the same error :(

Here is the code I have tried so far

**results.html**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        $('#pdfcon').click(function () {
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            var source = $('#pdfco').html();
            var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            doc.fromHTML(source, 0.5, 0.5, {
                'width': 75,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='jspdf/plugins/addhtml.js') }}"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='jspdf/plugins/from_html.js') }}"></script> 
<script  type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='jspdf/plugins/javascript.js') }}"></script>
```

**the file which is loaded using JQuery load**

```
<div class="row" id="pdfco">
    {% for ch_name,key,question in chart_data %}

    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-6">

    <br>

</label>{{key}}.&nbsp;{{question}}<label>
    <br>

    <br>
    {{charts[ch_name]}}


</div>
<br>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
</div>
```

**the exact error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: element.className.split is not a function
    at elementHandledElsewhere (jspdf.debug.js:7215)
    at DrillForContent (jspdf.debug.js:7426)
    at DrillForContent (jspdf.debug.js:7427)
    at DrillForContent (jspdf.debug.js:7427)
    at DrillForContent (jspdf.debug.js:7427)
    at DrillForContent (jspdf.debug.js:7427)
    at DrillForContent (jspdf.debug.js:7427)
    at DrillForContent (jspdf.debug.js:7427)
    at jspdf.debug.js:7595
    at done (jspdf.debug.js:7470)
```

Comment: Instead of `var source = $('#pdfco').html();` try `var source = $('#pdfco')[0]`.

Comment: @Titus still the same is it because of the jquery load function?

Comment: I don't think so, I thought the problem was that you were passing a string instead of a HTML element to the `doc.fromHTML` function.

Comment: @Titus any other ideas ? I can't figure out whats wrong.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and found by debbuging the fromHTML code that svg Elements were returning an ``SVGAnimatedString`` as their ``className``!

Comment: Ohh. I actually moved this to server side.

Comment: PaulCO have you got any solution?

Comment: @yasir_mughal try doing it server side.